# Do something while the program is computing

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to create a program that has to deal with some fairly long computations (some minutes). During said computation, the program would print a message every time it stumbles upon some data. So far, so good.

Now for the tricky part: how can I make so that, if the program doesn't print anything for a certain amount of time, some other action takes place?

I.e.:

```
while(true){
    //do stuff
    if(good stuff happens) System.out.println("GOTCHA!");
    if(nothing happens for some seconds)
        System.out.println("Don't worry, I'm still running!");
}
```

As you can see, I'm working in Java, but C/C++ would be ok, too.

Comment: You really should reconsider your tags before someone else did that.

Comment: Depending upon what that "other stuff" is, you could do this using multithreading. Or the brute force way would be, if your computations involve some kind of loop, do bits of "other stuff" as one of the loop tasks. It really depends a lot on what all this "stuff" is.

Comment: A program is a list of instructions that the computer carries out.  In a single-threaded environment, you can't ask it to do something when it is idle, because it isn't when its running.  It is a bit like talking to yourself and asking yourself if you're busy.  Conversations require more than one person, wouldn't you say?  What you're asking isn't possible (not truly) without the use of threads in some form.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should start a new thread. Have a look at [cuncurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). It's classified as "essential", this is why I'm just suggesting to have a look by yourself and not giving a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from the `System` javadoc.

For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute: 
`long startTime = System.nanoTime();`

// ... the code being measured ...

`long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;`

Answer (score 0):

A [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) can help you with this.

You can schedule some function to run every `n` seconds, have it check if the computation is still running and, if it is running, output some message or whatever. Once computations are done you can stop the executor or just cancel your scheduled task in case you want to use the executor for other tasks.

The executor service will provide and manage its own background thread(s), so that you don't have to deal with that, while your computation can still run continuously on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides something similar which is not able to provide progress per se but is able to manage an asynchronous task which is the [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) class. Since you need to provide to the user a feedback of the current operating task you would need at least two threads (the `Future<T>` thread and the reporting one), something like:

```
public class ReportThread extends Thread {
  final int delay;
  boolean finished;

  ReportThread() { finished = false; }
  void done() { finished = true; }

  public void run() {
    while (!finished) {    
      Thread.sleep(delay);
      System.out.println("Computing long task..");
    }
  }
}

ReportThread report = new ReportThread(1000);
report.start();
ExecutorService service = new ExecutorService();
Future<T> future = service.submit(new Future<T>(new Callable<T>() {
  public T call() {
    // long task implementation
  })
);
T result = future.get();
report.done();
```

The idea is the following, you will have to take care about exceptions where required.

It should be possible to use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule either your computing operation (with a delay of 0 and no fixed rate) either your reporting task (with a initial delay and a fixed rate) so that you can wait while getting the result of the first to then cancel the second.